# PUT and POST methods work in Postman but only POST works in Angular 10

Tags: angular, visual-studio, webapi, angular10

This in my "edit-continent.component.ts"

```js
    addContinent(continentData) {
        this.continent.name = continentData.name;
        this.continentService.addContinent(this.continent).subscribe((response) => {
          (data) =>
            (this.continent = {
              id: (data as any).id,
              name: (data as any).name,
            });
          this.ngOnInit(), this.continentForm.reset();
        });
      }
    
      editContinent(continentData) {
        this.continent.id = this.continentId;
        this.continent.name = continentData.name;
    
        console.log(`${this.continentId}`);
        console.log(`${continentData.name}`);
        console.log(this.continent);
    
        this.continentService.editContinent(this.continent).subscribe((response) => {
          (data) =>
            (this.continent = {
              id: (data as any).id,
              name: (data as any).name,
            });
          this.ngOnInit(), this.continentForm.reset();
        });
      }

(the console.logs all print what they are suppose to)

This is my "continent.service.ts"

    addContinent(continent: Continent): Observable<Continent> {
        return this.http
          .post<Continent>(this.url, continent, httpOptions)
          .pipe(retry(2), catchError(this.handleError)); //tenta novamente por 2x
      }
    
      editContinent(continent: Continent): Observable<Continent> {
        const apiurl = `${this.url}/${continent.id}`;

        console.log(continent);
        console.log(apiurl);

        return this.http
          .put<Continent>(apiurl, continent, httpOptions)
          .pipe(retry(2), catchError(this.handleError));
      }
```

(the console.logs also print what they are suppose to)
And this in my Web API in Visual Studio (using Dapper and SQL Server)

```php
    [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult PostContinent (Continent continent)
            {
                int i = ContinentRepository.PostContinent(continent);
                continent.Id = i;
                if (i > 0)
                    return Ok(continent);
                return NotFound();
            }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult PutContinent(long id, Continent continent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id.ToString(), continent);
        if (id != continent.Id)
            return BadRequest();

        int i = ContinentRepository.PutContinent(continent);
        if (i > 0)
            return Ok(continent);
        return NotFound();
    }
```

They work in Postman, but only the POST method works in Angular, the PUT method gives me this error:

```
    X PUT https://localhost:44306/continent/4 400
    X Backend returned code 400, body was: [object Object]
    X Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngOriginalError' of undefined
        at getOriginalError (core.js:4346)
        at ErrorHandler._findOriginalError (core.js:4418)
        at ErrorHandler.handleError (core.js:4395)
        at Object.next (core.js:28037)
        at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:24851)
        at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
        at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
        at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
        at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
        at EventEmitter_.next (Subject.js:39)
```

I also have the AddCors in the Startup of my api

```php
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                [...]
                services.AddCors(c =>
                {
                    c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());
                });
                services.AddControllers();
            }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
    [...]
    }
```

I tried several different things but don't know why is giving me this errors, I guess is something about the object "continent" I'm passing as a parameter, but since it works for POST (also for GET and DELETE but I didn't think it was relevant) I don't see why it wouldn't for PUT

**Edit:**
I tried using [FromBody] in [HttpPut("{id}")] but it didn't work. When using dynamic instead of Continent it's possible to see that it gets:

```
ValueKind = Object : "{"id":"90002","name":"oi"}"
error CS0726: ':' is not a valid format specifier
```

What should I do?

Comment: HTTP status code 400 is Bad Request, and `PutContinent` returns that if the id specified in the URL is not the same as the id specified in the `Continent` object given in the body. Guess that's where I'd start...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I tried removing the bad request, removing all the code and just returning string or the object itself, nothing worked. I don't think it evens enters the put method

Comment: Actually, looking at that error makes me think something's amiss `body was [object Object]` seems like it's saying the data was not stringified. I thought Angular's HttpClient did that automatically... Maybe something in `httpOptions`?

Comment: Change input type on api to dynamic then breakpoint on entry. This allows you to see if its a server side binding issue.

Comment: @JohnPeters Tried the dynamic and api is giving me: `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:''System.Text.Json.JsonElement' does not contain a definition for 'Id''`. So it's not receiving an object. Maybe I need to change something in the `httpOptions` like @HereticMonkey said.

Comment: OK problem is telling you the runtime binder cannot find the json property ID to create a model. What does the Client side body look like?

Comment: @JohnPeters Client body: `export class Continent {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}` Only difference is that the names are not caps, but I tried like Id and Name but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out it was the id type I was sending. It was in string format instead of long, but I failed to notice before. This solved the problem.

```
editContinent(continentData) {

    this.continent.id = Number(this.continentId);
    this.continent.name = continentData.name;

    this.continentService
      .editContinent(this.continent)
      .subscribe((data : Continent) =>
      {
          this.continent = data;
          this.continentForm.reset();
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your put you need to tell it that the continent is coming from the body.

`public IActionResult PutContinent(long id, [FromBody]Continent continent)`